# Get index of symbol in FormattedText at the given Point

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

We have FormattedText object, coordinates x, y (point).

How to find index of symbol in text by that coordinates.

Is there a way to find rectangles of each characters in FormattedText quickly?

Comment: I found a slow method: for ex., 5th char rect is formattedText.BuildHighlightGeometry(new Point(), 5, 1).Bounds;